# U-SQL View concurrent read & drop

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Suppose, I have a U-SQL view. There is one job running that is reading data from the view. At the same time, another job wants to drop and re-create the view.

What would happen when the second job tries to drop the view while it is being used by the first job? Will the second job automatically wait? Or will it just drop the view? What impact will it have on the first job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are inline so if the View is available at the compilation time of first job and first job is running for 5 hours, it will continue to work, even if the second job has dropped the View. If View is not available at the compilation time then job will fail.

Hope this helps!
Amina